# Angular как сделать задержку get запроса

Tags: javascript, angular

Есть код

```
 return this.http.get(`${this.BASE_URL}${url}`)
            .pipe(map((response: HttpResponse<any>) => response));
```

Как сделать чтоб запрос выполнялся не сразу, а допустим через 2-3 секунды, пробовал добавить delay(2000) но тут все равно запрос отправляет моментально, только результат с задержкой

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте фабрику `timer` и оператор `mergeMap`, который подпишется на `http.get` после задержки и вы получите ответ от сервера:

```
import { timer } from 'rxjs';
import { mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

return timer(2000).pipe(
  mergeMap(() => this.http.get(`${this.BASE_URL}${url}`))
);
```

И кстати на заметку `HttpClient.prototype.get` не возвращает `Observable<HttpResponse<any>>`, а `Observable<Object>`, если не перегружать тип

Comment: Спасибо, только вот по.  И кстати на заметку HttpClient.prototype.get не возвращает Observable<HttpResponse<any>>, а Observable<Object>, если не перегружать тип  не понял

Comment: @Ricco381 вы в колбеке `map` указываете тип `response: HttpResponse<any>`, это неверно, там тип `response: Object`. Если код вам помог - то пометьте его галочкой :)

Comment: Ещё не проверял, но думаю поможет) Ещё не получает сделать кнопку с лоудером когда отправляется допустим запрос на сервер чтоб было понятно что что-то происходит и нужно подождать, все пересмотрел так и не нашел(

Comment: а где находится этот лоадер? он должен показываться всегда на каждый запрос или ...?

Comment: Ну да, сам лоудер ещё нигде потому что я не могу понять как это реализовать. Допустим есть форма, при нажатии на кнопку идёт отправка Ина сервер и в этот момент должен появится сппинет вместо надписи, после окончания надпись должна вернуться

Comment: создайте вопрос на СО - я постараюсь вам помочь

Comment: Что такое СО?))

Comment: stack overflow :D

Comment: Вопрос создал.)